# Do a pymongo Query with elemmatch and filter

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following data structure:

```
[
    {
        "site_id": ObjectId("5e85b9d20498abd407e9a030"),
        "status": "ERROR"
    },
    {
        "site_id": ObjectId("5e85b9d20498abd407e9a120"),
        "status": "ERROR"
    },
    {
        "site_id": ObjectId("5e85b9d20498abd407e9a030"),
        "status": "OK",
        "risk_categories": [
            {

                "position": 1,
                "category_id": 1414,
            },
            {

                "position": 2,
                "category_id": 1402,

            },
            {

                "position": 3,
                "category_id": 1392,

            }
                ]
    }
]
```

I want to make a query with pymongo like this:

collection.find_one(filter=filter)

where: 
filter = {'$and': [{'$and': [{'site_id': ObjectId('5e85b9d20498abd407e9a030')}, {'status': 'OK'}]}, {'risk_categories': {'$elemMatch': {'$or': [{'position': {'$eq': 1}}, {'position': {'$eq': 2}}]}}}]}

however, it returns me the entire object. Not only the values of risk categories that I want.
What can I do on my filter to modify that?

Comment: With `$elemMatch` projection operator you can filter on the array element's field (e.g., `position`), but the output will show only the _first_ matching array element. There is no feature to return two elements (like position = 1 or 2) as in the posted document. The only other option is use an aggregation.

Comment: If it's possible with Aggregation, that's also fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aggregation runs from `mongo` shell:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match:  { 
          site_id: ObjectId('5e85b9d20498abd407e9a030'), 
          status: "OK" 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: {
          risk_categories: { 
              $filter: { 
                  input: "$risk_categories", 
                  as: "cat",
                  cond: {
                      $in: [ "$$cat.position", [ 1, 2 ] ]    // this is equivalent to using the "$or"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
] ).pretty()
```

The output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e85c7b6724e461876467077"),
        "site_id" : ObjectId("5e85b9d20498abd407e9a030"),
        "status" : "OK",
        "risk_categories" : [
                {
                        "position" : 1,
                        "category_id" : 1414
                },
                {
                        "position" : 2,
                        "category_id" : 1402
                }
        ]
}
```

---

Using PyMongo 3.9 and MongoDB 4.2, from the Python shell:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.test
collection = db.collection
import pprint
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

pipeline = [
  { 
      '$match':  { 
          'site_id': ObjectId('5e85b9d20498abd407e9a030'), 
          'status': 'OK'
      } 
  },
  { 
      '$addFields': {
          'risk_categories': { 
              '$filter': { 
                  'input': '$risk_categories', 
                  'as': 'cat',
                  'cond': {
                      '$in': [ '$$cat.position', [ 1, 2 ] ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
]

pprint.pprint(list(collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```